# Pandas- enabling ANSI encoding for read excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, encoding

I want to read an excel file and store it in dataframe. I am using pandas dataframe to read, but my excel workbook is encoded in ANSI. Newer pandas version has removed the encoding feature all together as thus i cant use ANSI encoded dataset and i am loosing important data cause of it.

```
DFIT_FILE = r'C:\Users\kyzx\Documents\clone12\abc\blob-quickstart-v12\data\myecel.xlsx'
df1 = pd.read_excel(DFIT_FILE, sheet_name='Guidance MASTER')
```

I would be grateful if i could get a workaround for this. Thanks in advance

I have already tried replacing it with this , it hasnt worked yet

```
DFIT_FILE = r'C:\Users\kidutta\Documentsbc\a\ITS-CSD-Advisory-DFIT\blob-quickstart-v12\data\myexcelsheet.xlsx'
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(DFIT_FILE, encoding_override="cp1252")
df2 = pd.read_excel(wb, sheet_name='Eligible Costs MASTER')
```

Comment: Excel files are binary, they never had codepages or encodings. `xlsx` files are ZIP packages containing XML files. Why are you asking this? What's the actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: Also UTF-8 is completely backward compatible with ANSI. What do you mean you are losing data?

Comment: `i am loosing important data` what does that mean? Whatever it means, it's not due to encodings. Perhaps you don't have an Excel file at all - many lazy developers generate text or HTML files with a fake `xlsx` extension and call them "Excel files". Excel isn't fooled and *imports* those files using the user's locale defaults for field separators, numbers, dates *and* encodings. This leads to problems if the developers used different settings from the users

Comment: By loosing data some of my datum are getting converted into formats like these 

Â

Comment: @topsail: no. UTF-8 is not completely backward compatible: a code point above 127 is encoded with two bytes in UTF-8 and one byte in the wrongly called "ANSI encoding".

Comment: Okay my bad I was thinking plain old ascii (which is usually what I think when I hear "ansi"). Are there values in this excel file that are not plain old ascii? Can you provide a reproducible example? For example, you say you "get a datum converted into formats like `Â`" - well, what are these datums?

Comment: Also perhaps you should explain how you chose the option `encoding_override="cp1252"` - why did you do this? Since it isn't working, what else have you tried?